# How can I prevent data loss when saving web socket messages to mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, real-time

I am trying to implement a websocket realtime chat system in nodejs. I already have a login system in place and the websocket chat system. The only thing I'm stuck on is saving the messages to MySQL so that the user can access their chat history. The problem is that I don't want to send a web socket message to the recipient then have the MySQL insert fail for whatever reason.

**A possible solution:**
The obvious solution is to save the message data in MySQL *then* send the web socket message to the recipient. If there is an error, send that back to the sender instead of sending the message. Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of web sockets though, if the server has to wait for a MySQL insert success confirmation?

Comment: Websockets or Socket.io ?

Comment: Defeat the purpose in what way?

Comment: We are talking about some milliseconds. The user will not even perceive the latency introduced by saving to mysql. If he does, there is likely problem with your query or the server.

Comment: @kalanaDemel It's websockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a big deal because you want to avoid a small amount of latency waiting for a database save (which I think is not actually a problem to do that)..Send the message.  On the screen, display 'sending message..'
On the server, initiate the asynchronous database save.
When the other user's client receives the message, send print an
acknowledgement on the sender's screen
When the database save on the server completes, you dont have to do anything, unless it gives an error in which case you can inform the user there was an error saving the message and then retry the save.

Some systems like Google Hangouts during voice/video don't even try to save chat history.

You are only really going to have a problem if your database server runs out of space or goes down, in which case you have bigger problems and your error messages will clue the users in.

Or you can wait to save in the database, it isn't a huge amount of time to wait.  Also, websockets and socket.io always go to the server anyway.  If you were using WebRTC Data Channels, *that* is a peer 2 peer protocol that would not involve the server.